# how modify mobile responsive version structure in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

i have a responsive wordpress theme.
In the desktop version it's load some elements (for example a jquery carousel).
I'd like that in mobile version, it doesn't load some component (the carousel for example).
Is it possibile ? How ?
Only with css with disply:none ? in this way it's load anyway script.
Could someone help me ?
Thanks and excuse me for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to make sure your div is not hidden within your mobile media query in your stylesheet (probably style.css)

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 319px) and (max-device-width: 640px){ 
/*carousel NOT display:none;*/
}
```

The second is to play with responsive jQuery. There's a lot to learn but this Bones theme script may get you started:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    /*
    Responsive jQuery is a tricky thing.
    There's a bunch of different ways to handle
    it, so be sure to research and find the one
    that works for you best.
    */

    /* getting viewport width */
    var responsive_viewport = $(window).width();

    /* if is below 481px */
    if (responsive_viewport < 481) {

    } /* end smallest screen */

    /* if is larger than 481px */
    if (responsive_viewport > 481) {

    } /* end larger than 481px */

    /* if is above or equal to 768px */
    if (responsive_viewport >= 768) {

        /* load gravatars */
        $('.comment img[data-gravatar]').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('data-gravatar'));
        });

    }

    /* off the bat large screen actions */
    if (responsive_viewport > 1030) {

    }
```